# document set document export as zip with metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint 2013 Environment i have a Document set with 1 or more documents. On a button click i want to Export all these documents and with the document set metadata(as .XML file) as zip file in another document library. 
How can do these ?..

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article on Download Document Set as zip below:
https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2010/07/22/download-document-set-as-zip/

Comment: I tried it in but it's not working.